# Command-line invocation of unittests from __main__ failing

Tags: python, command-line, runtime-error, command-line-arguments, python-unittest

I am solving some exercises in Python and using unittest to automate some of the verification of my code. One program runs the single unittest just fine and it passes. The second gives the following error:

```
$ python s1c6.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: s1c6 (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 's1c6'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Here's the code for the working script:

```
# s1c5.py
import unittest

import cryptopals


class TestRepeatingKeyXor(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCase(self):
        key = b"ICE"
        data = b"Burning 'em, if you ain't quick and nimble\nI go crazy when I hear a cymbal"
        expected = bytes.fromhex(
            "0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272a282b2f20430a652e2c652a3124333a653e2b2027630c692b20283165286326302e27282f")
        self.assertEqual(expected, cryptopals.xorcrypt(key, data))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And the code for the failing script:

```
# s1c6.py
import unittest
import bitstring

import cryptopals


class TestHammingDistance(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCase(self):
        str1 = b'this is a test'
        str2 = b'wokka wokka!!!'
        expected = 37
        self.assertEqual(expected, hamming_distance(str1, str2))


def hamming_distance(str1, str2):
    temp = cryptopals.xor(str1, str2)
    return sum(bitstring.Bits(temp))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I do not see a fundamental difference between these two programs that would cause an error in one and not the other. What am I missing?

```
import itertools
import operator


def xor(a, b):
    return bytes(map(operator.xor, a, b))


def xorcrypt(key, cipher):
    return b''.join(xor(key, x) for x in grouper(cipher, len(key)))


def grouper(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    group = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
    while group:
        yield group
        group = tuple(itertools.islice(it, n))
```

"Raw" version of failing script:

```
# s1c6_raw.py
import cryptopals

key = b"ICE"
data = b"Burning 'em, if you ain't quick and nimble\nI go crazy when I hear a cymbal"
expected = bytes.fromhex(
    "0b3637272a2b2e63622c2e69692a23693a2a3c6324202d623d63343c2a26226324272765272a282b2f20430a652e2c652a3124333a653e2b2027630c692b20283165286326302e27282f")
print(cryptopals.xorcrypt(key, data))
```

The above runs fine and prints the expected output.

Comment: What happens if you take the code inside the failing test case, put it in a file by itself (along with the necessary imports), and run it?

Comment: How did you install cryptopals? It is not on PyPi, is it?

Comment: @Eddie cryptopals is my own .py file in the same directory as both of the ones shown.

Comment: @BrenBarn If I run the "failing" script as a "Python test" in PyCharm, it runs fine (and currently passes, but that's not significant). The "failure" occurs when I run from the command line as shown or with a "Python" run configuration in PyCharm.

Comment: Could you post what is inside cryptopals.py?

Comment: @Eddie It is about 80 lines of functions.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I don't know about "Python test", I mean what happens if you eliminate `unittest` from your procedure and run the failing code "raw", not as part of any test case.

Comment: @Eddie I have posted the three methods from cryptopals.py which are used in the other two programs.

Comment: @BrenBarn I have added a "raw" version to my question. Is that what you mean? I modified the last line to just print out the result since `assertEqual()` is not available outside the test class.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Okay.  Can you clarify what you're doing in PyCharm vs not in PyCharm?  Like, there are four possibilities: 1) you run the unittest code from PyCharm; 2) you run the unittest code from the command line; 3) you run the raw code from PyCharm; 4) you run the raw code from the command line.  As I understand it, you're saying #4 works without error, but I'm not clear on the others.

Comment: @BrenBarn If you are familiar with PyCharm it has what are called "Run Configurations". One is called "Python" which basically runs the command line `python <script>`. The other is "Python tests" which searches the script for subclasses of `unittest.TestCase` and runs them. I don't know the exact details of the underlying command line. When I run the "failing script" in my question as a "Python tests" run configuration, it works just fine. However, when I run it as a "Python" run configuration, I get the same error as when I run from the command line".

Comment: @BrenBarn As I said, I don't know the details of what "Python tests" does under the hood. I suspect some reflection which imports my script in such a way that the `if` statement fails.

Comment: Then please `print "__name__ =", __name__`

Comment: @smci When I run `python s1c6.py` or the "Python" run config in PyCharm, I get `__name__: __main__`. When I run the "Python tests" run config in PyCharm, I get `__name__: s1c6`.

Comment: And apparently I left out an important detail: I was running the script with a command line argument `python s1c6.py s1c6.txt` This seems to be causing the error.

Comment: Both sets of code fail for me when the command line arg is present

Comment: @StephenRauch Yup, because `unittest.main()` is parsing the args. I never ran the other script with args, so that's the fundamental difference I was missing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Then can't you just not use the "Python tests" thing?  What does it gain you?

Comment: @BrenBarn Well, it worked the way I wanted by running the tests when running from the command line didn't. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that I was running the two scripts in different ways:

```
$ python s1c5.py
```

and

```
$ python s1c6.py s1c6.txt
```

Since `unittest.main()` parses command line arguments, there is an error in the second case. If I pass a command line argument to the first program, I also get the same error.